# Generate multiple documents at once using laravel/ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have in my view a multiple checkboxes.

So I'm trying to when I click on an element generates a document file of this checked element.

So I'm passing with my ajax request multiples ids at once and then generate multiple document files according to each sent id by ajax request.

The following script describes what I'm doing :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#numero_projet').change(function() {
            var id_projet = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
            $('#generer').click(function() {
            var checkValues = [];
            $.each($("input[name='casting_checked']:checked"), function() {            
                checkValues.push($(this).data('id'));
            });
            console.log(checkValues);
            $.ajax({
                url: "generer/"+id_projet+"/"+checkValues,
                type: 'get',
                 headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                   data: {ids:checkValues},
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
            });
          });
      });
   });
</script>
```

The `checkValues` in my console:

```
(3) [15, 17, 19]
0: 15
1: 17
2: 19
length: 3
```

And in my controller I have the following code :

```
public function generer(){
    $id_projet = request('id_projet');
    $id_casting = request('ids');
    $id_contrat = Projet_Casting::where('id_projet',$id_projet)->where('id_casting',$id_casting)->value('id_contrat');
    $id_modele_contrat = Contrat::where('id_contrat',$id_contrat)->value('id_modele_contrat');
    $model_file = Model_Contrat::where('id_modele_contrat',$id_modele_contrat)->value('fichier');
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('C:/Users/ss/Documents/GitHub/casting/storage/app/public/uploads/modeles_contrat/'.$model_file);
    $filename= $id_contrat;
    $templateProcessor->saveAs( $filename.'.docx');
    return response()->download( $filename.'.docx');
}
```

The problem is this code generates only one document and not multiple documents as in this case my ajax request sent an array with tree ids it should generate tree documents.

And when I did `dd( $id_contrat);` for example I get one value and not tree values.

What is wrong with my code? is this the correct way to do this thing? If you have any idea, any suggestion please help.

Comment: you can send ids using `checkValues.join()` as comma separated string

Comment: @elegant-user , thank you for your help , but how can I do tha ? I want for each id senf by ajax generate a document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending an array to a function which returns one file. Perhaps loop through the array to generate the files and send back an array of files?

alternately, loop through the array in JS and you'll get back a file for each item in the array. That is one ajax call for each element in the array.

Comment: thank you for your answer n I"m still beginner in ajax , please if you can explain more how can I loop through the array in JS and get back a file for each item in the array

Comment: You could move the ajax call into $.each function, replace this line checkValues.push($(this).data('id')); with the ajax call and send [$(this).data('id')] in place of checkvalues assuming the function expects an array